# verifier.pdb is not forund

Tags: visual-c++, application-verifier

ALL,

I'm trying to develop my app on Windows 8.1 with MSVC 2017.

I recently updated it (the original install was couple of years old) and now when I try to run it from the IDE I get an error:

`verifier.pdb is not loaded`.

What is this and why I didn't get it from the original version?

I presume that this verifier.dll is a good thing and will help me with the development in the long run, but right now it prevents me from debugging my application.

Could someone please help.

TIA!!

P.S.: I'm adding `application-verifier` tag, but I'm not sure that it is related. I apologize in advance if its not.

EDIT:

That question is related but the answer{s} there does **NOT** explain how to remove the error I'm seeing.

Moreover the linked question does **not** see the issue I'm having.

So those 2 - mine and the linked one - are NOT duplicates.

Also, I'd appreciate if the question I'm posting is not closed immediately - post the **CONSIDERED** dup and give me a time to respond.

On top of that the link referenced in one the comment still doesn't work and the updated one does **NOT** say how to cancel the specific error I'm seeing.

And finally - the lionked question was talking about debugging the application with the RT.

I am starting the application inside MSVC and so I **don't** have **ANY** means to continue running the application, while the presumed OP seems to imply the application was running fine after starting and therefore was able to perform the task semi-successfully.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

It is application verifier.
I am guessing this is the original issue - [Mysterious verifier.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503192/mysterious-verifier-dll)